# httaccess 301 redirect for multiple file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have few urls  (e.g. helloworld.com/test-1-xyz.html, helloworld.com/test-1-abc.html)which needs to be redirected to a single url (helloworld.com/test-1-contact.html)

So far, I have done this

```
RewriteRule ^test-1-(.*)$ contact.html [NC,L,R=301]
```

but it is not working. any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What you have will probably work if you change `contact.html` to `test-1-contact.html`. It looks like you were trying to use the second RewriteRule arg as a replacement for only the `(.*)` but it should be complete final path.

Comment: You might need to clear your cache thoroughly before it works though, browsers will hold onto the 301 redirect from your failed attempts

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(test-1)-.*$ /$1-contact.html [NC,L,R=301]` should work fine